# what sort of mac/chrome hack could produce this kind of spam?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spam-prevention

this

[image: screenshot]

is obviously spam. things like this happen randomly, but not often, on this macbook (el capitan) in chrome (61.0.3163.100).

I have no idea where to start looking. I installed malwarebytes, it finds nothing. Is my dns hijacked ? Is the router hacked ? Is chrome itself infected ? Any ideas ?

Comment: https://isc.sans.edu/diary/.COM.COM+Used+For+Malicious+Typo+Squatting/20019 explains what's happening, except com.com sometimes redirects to .xyz domains these days.

Comment: Start by looking at and removing suspicious addons in Chrome. Nothing to do with the OS directly.

Comment: The official website for ziggo is `https://www.ziggo.nl/`. Why are you trying to load `ziggo b. v.`?

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't try to go anywhere. I just open the browser and this pops up. I've seen variations of this.